# Why am I getting error in svg path tag attributes?

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

Why am I getting error in react for these attributes?

```
stroke-linecap="square"
stroke-linejoin="round"
```

should they be like - strokeLinecap, strokeLinejoin?

```
           <svg
              width="36"
              height="22"
              viewBox="0 0 36 22"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M26.1012 1.64432L34.9639 10.9994L26.1012 20.3545"
                stroke="black"
                stroke-linecap="square"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
              />
              <line
                x1="35"
                y1="11.043"
                x2="-4.37114e-08"
                y2="11.043"
                stroke="black"
              />
            </svg>
```

Comment: As this is a purely SVG-related question I deleted the react and next.js tags.

Comment: Ah - I am sorry to have missed that point! Thanks for the clarification @RobertLongson !

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe it fits the question better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just learned that in react attribute names of JSX elements are not allowed to have hyphens in them. I hoped that the following could be a workaround (as it turns out - read further below - it isn't!)? I put the "critical" attributes into a single `style` attribute. I also adjusted your `width`, `height` and `viewBox` attributes (and added a `stroke-width` attribute). Now you can see that the `stroke-linecap` and `stroke-linejoin` attributes basically work as intended (but not in react ...):

```html
<svg width="215" height="130"
     viewBox="-3 -2 43 26" fill="none"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M26.1012 1.64432L34.9639 10.9994L26.1012 20.3545"
       style="stroke:black; stroke-width:5; stroke-linecap:square; stroke-linejoin:round" />
 <line x1="32" y1="11.043"
       x2="0" y2="11.043"
       style="stroke:orange; stroke-width:5; stroke-linecap:round" />
 <rect stroke="blue" style="stroke-width:.2" width="36" height="22" />
</svg>
```

I also changed a few of the `line` attributes to make it easier to demonstrate which bits of the SVG diagram are rounded and which ones aren't.

And I added a `rect` element with your original `viewBox` coordinates to illustrate how in your version the corners of the arrow would have been clipped.

Admittedly, I have never worked with react before. Therefore it came as a surprise to me how *different* these JSX elements are to "normal" DOM elements. It appears to me that the `style` attribute cannot be used in JSX svg elements. So, the solution suggested above will not work in react. Below I built a react snippet with the camelized version of the attributes. This also worked for OP.

**React snippet:**

```js
// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
<svg width="215" height="130"
     viewBox="-3 -2 43 26" fill="none"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M26.1012 1.64432L34.9639 10.9994L26.1012 20.3545"
       stroke="black"  strokeWidth="5" strokeLinecap="square" strokeLinejoin="round" />
 <line x1="32" y1="11.043"
       x2="0" y2="11.043"
       stroke="orange" strokeWidth="5" strokeLinecap="round" />
 <rect stroke="blue" strokeWidth=".2" width="36" height="22" />
</svg>  ,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have just used
strokeLinecap="square"
strokeLinejoin="round"
that works fine for me